# location of .htaccess in bitnami wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, nginx-config

i am not able to find the location of .htaccess file in bitnami wordpress. Need to enable content scripting policy in .htaccess file. But this file doesnot exits in nginx bitnami wordpress. Could anyone please help to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The .htaccess files are used by Apache to modify the configuration of the application per directory. We do not suggest any user use them because of security and performance reasons. However, you are asking about the WordPress with NGINX solution. NGINX doesn't make use of the .htaccess files so if your plugin/theme needs any custom configuration, you will need to include it inside the NGINX conf. There is a specific configuration file for WordPress at /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/nginx-app.conf.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: If we are not to use the .htaccess file, what *should* we do?

Answer (score -2):

Check Here

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/">
 Your code here
</Directory>
```

Comment: Learn About The Bitnami Support Tool,  https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/understand-bnsupport/